# Screenshot of active window doesn't work

Tags: 10.10, window, screenshot

Ubuntu 10.10
Screenshot of full screen works. Screenshot of "selected area" works. But Screenshot of current (active) window doesn't. Nothing happens. The save screenshot window doesn't open.

Tried using Alt+Print as well as from the Panel->Accessories->Screenshot. Same result. No screenshot.

Any ideas?

Comment: GIMP window screenshot works. But thats not the point. Why doesn't the normal way work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Change the delay from 0 sec to 4 or 5 seconds and then try.

[image: Screenshot of ScreenShot window]

Hope you got the reason why it was not working.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for that. Another answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/258735/ubuntu-10-10-screenshot-of-active-window-doesnt-work). The problem is that Alt+Print conflicts with kernel Magis SysRq key in Ubuntu 10.10. So changing the keyboard shortcut to something else does the trick.